# No DNS on server after bringing up Wireguard Server

Tags: dns, wireguard

I have a server running Fedora 38 that I'm using as a Wireguard VPN server. The Wireguard VPN works fine - clients can connect and are able to browse the internet. However, whenever the Wireguard VPN service is up, there's no DNS on the server.

My Wireguard VPN server settings:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = CKLF/SOMEPRIVATEKEY
Address = 10.0.2.1/24
ListenPort = 51820

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE

DNS = 8.8.8.8
SaveConfig = false

# Client1
[Peer]
PublicKey = SOMEPUBLICKEY
PresharedKey = SOMEPRESHAREDKEY
AllowedIPs = 10.0.2.2/32

# Client2
[Peer]
PublicKey = SOMEPUBLICKEY
PresharedKey = SOMEPRESHAREDKEY
AllowedIPs = 10.0.2.3/32
```

When I bring up the Wireguard interface:

```
# systemctl start wg-quick@homeserver
# ping serverfault.com
ping: serverfault.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

# nslookup serverfault.com
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; no servers could be reached
```

When I take it down:

```
# systemctl stop wg-quick@homeserver.service 
# ping serverfault.com
PING serverfault.com (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=2.03 ms

# nslookup serverfault.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
```

What do I need to do to get DNS works on the server when my `homeserver` Wireguard server is up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `DNS =` entry from the server .conf file altogether. This way, you will use the server's DNS settings.

If you want to use `DNS =` entry, you should disable systemd-resolved's stub DNS resolver. This should do the trick:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d

cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/SOMECONFFILE.conf
[Resolve]
DNSStubListener=no
EOF

systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

And you are using `8.8.8.8` or whatever DNS server you configured in WG's .conf file.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved the issue! I removed the DNS entry, my server now has DNS when the Wireguard Server is activated.